# Assign a boolean value to the key inside the object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to come up with the way to loop through an array of values, save each value as a key and assign a 'true' boolean value for each key.

The goal is to create the following object:

```
{
  "arrayValue" : true,
  "anotherArrayValue" : true,
  "arrayValueAsWell" : true
}
```

I am doing:

```
  var objectToCreate = {};

  let myArray = ["arrayValue", "anotherArrayValue", "arrayValueAsWell"]
  let myArrayConverted = myArray.forEach((prop,index) => objectToCreate[prop] = true)
```

and getting:

```
  {
    0 : "arrayValue",
    1 : "anotherArrayValue",
    2 : "arrayValueAsWell"
  }
```

Comment: `objectToCreate[prop] = true;` — there's no need to create a capital-B Boolean object.

Comment: @Pointy tried this way too, same result

Comment: Your edited code returns - > `{ arrayValue: true, anotherArrayValue: true, arrayValueAsWell: true}` isn't that what you want ?

Comment: Why are you mixing `var` and `let`?

Comment: Just to note, `myArrayConverted` will be `undefined`. `Array.prototype.forEach()` returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**return**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Return_value) value of `forEach()` is `undefined`. You also should assign the value to the object key with assignment (`=`) operator:

```js
var objectToCreate = {};
let myArray = ["arrayValue", "anotherArrayValue", "arrayValueAsWell"];
myArray.forEach(prop => objectToCreate[prop] = true);
console.log(objectToCreate);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to create an object with the keys like this:

```
const myObject = ["arrayValue", "anotherArrayValue", "arrayValueAsWell"]
  .reduce((acc, value) => ({ ...acc, [value]: true }), {});

console.log(myObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the array and assign to the `objectToCreate`, like this:

```
  var objectToCreate = {};
  let myArray = ["arrayValue", "anotherArrayValue", "arrayValueAsWell"];
  myArray.forEach(key => objectToCreate[key] = true)';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map object and assign them all to one object with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
var array = ["arrayValue", "anotherArrayValue", "arrayValueAsWell"],
    object = Object.assign(...array.map(k => ({ [k]: true })));

console.log(object);
```